# Server Error (500) Django App on AWS server

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2

Good day,

i have currently my django project running on an aws server. I have used Nginx and configured it all. The application is running, but when i try to login via the login page i have created or try to login via the admin panel it gives me a Server Error (500). I have my `DEBUG=False` and added my server dns to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. As for the Database. I have got my SQL Database running on an Azure server and used environment variables (that i have  permanently set in my ubuntu terminal) to get my password and username.

I have also tried to set DEBUG to False and trying to figure out the issue when running `python manage.py runserver` so i could experiment with it on my localhost, but no luck. I cant access  127.0.0.1 eventhough i have added it to my Allowed hosts.
How could i see what the error is? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so fixed it!

After each change, you simply run the command `sudo supervisorctl reload` in your powershell after you ssh'ed into your aws ec2 server.

As for seeing what the error is, simply set `DEBUG=True`